# How can I change from INSERT INTO to UPDATE

Tags: php, mysqli

(Sorry for my English writing)
This is my coding for insert data

```
  $insertChecklist = 'INSERT INTO checklists(`ADMIN_ID`, `COMPUTER_ID`) VALUES(?, ?);';
    $stmtChecklist = $connection->prepare($insertChecklist);
    $stmtChecklist->bind_param('ii', $_POST['ADMIN_ID'], $_POST['COMPUTER_ID']);

    $isInsert = $stmtChecklist->execute();
    $lastInsertId = mysqli_insert_id($connection);

    $stmtChecklist->close();

  $insertInstalledProgram = 'INSERT INTO checklist_programs(`CHECKLIST_ID`, `PROGRAM_ID`) VALUES(?, ?);';
  $stmtProgramId = $connection->prepare($insertInstalledProgram);
  $stmtProgramId->bind_param('ii', $lastInsertId, $programId);

  foreach ($_POST['PROGRAM_ID'] as $program)
  {
    $programId = $program;
    $stmtProgramId->execute();
  }
    $stmtProgramId->close();

    $connection->close();
    if ($isInsert) {
      // echo($lastInsertId);
      header('Location: OverViewCheckList.php');
      exit(0);
    }
```

And I need to change this `Insert into` to `Update`
I don't know how. Please help :(
Thank you.

Comment: It is not clear, also your code not sql safe.

Answer (score 1):

It is not clear what you really want
maybe something like that:

```
$updateChecklist = 'UPDATE checklists SET `ADMIN_ID` = ?, `COMPUTER_ID` = ? WHERE id = ?';
$stmtChecklist = $connection->prepare($insertChecklist);
$stmtChecklist->bind_param('iii', $_POST['ADMIN_ID'], $_POST['COMPUTER_ID'], $_POST['ID']);

$res = $stmtChecklist->execute();
```